# Rightscale::HttpConnection : re-raising same error: https://eu-central-1.ec2.amazonaws.com:443 temporarily unavailable

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm using chef_gem `"right_aws" version '3.0.5'`

```
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/aws#changelog
v2.5.0 (2014-10-22)
```

Got the following error when trying to use aws cookbook in ec2-central-1 region

```
WARN: Rightscale::HttpConnection : request failure count: 1, exception: #<SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known>
WARN: Rightscale::HttpConnection : request failure count: 2, exception: #<SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known>
WARN: Rightscale::HttpConnection : request failure count: 3, exception: #<SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known>
WARN: Rightscale::HttpConnection : request failure count: 4, exception: #<SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known>
WARN: Rightscale::HttpConnection : re-raising same error: https://eu-central-1.ec2.amazonaws.com:443 temporarily unavailable: (SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known) -- error count: 4, error age: 0
```

From this documentation 'http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html', 
the endpoint should be `'ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'`

I tried to edit my cookbook under `libraries-> ec2.rb`, but it doesn't work:

```
require 'open-uri'
module Opscode
  module Aws
    module Ec2
...

def ec2
    region = instance_availability_zone
    region = region[0, region.length-1]
    aws_ec2_endpoint = "https://ec2." + region + ".amazonaws.com"
    Chef::Log.debug("Using AWS EC2 endpoint: " + aws_ec2_endpoint)
    @@ec2 ||= create_aws_interface(RightAws::Ec2)
end
```

Any workarounds anyone can offer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the same issue, please find all details here:
https://github.com/rightscale/right_aws/issues/190